# facebook - get attending friends best practice

Tags: php, facebook, performance, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a list of facebook events, and I would like to retrieve the list of my friends who attending in each event.

This part done by the REST server:

```php
/**
 * $this->facebook is instance of `BaseFacebook`
 * $results contains 2 events
**/
$stime=time();

$fb_eids=array();
foreach($results as $result)
    $fb_eids[]=$result['event']->getFacebookID();

$fb_eids=implode(',',$fb_eids);
$fql=array();
$fql['q1'] = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()";
$fql['q2'] = <<<SQL
SELECT uid, eid FROM event_member WHERE 1
    AND eid IN({$fb_eids})
    AND rsvp_status = 'attending'
    AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #q1)
;
SQL;

var_dump($this->facebook->api(array('method'=>'fql.multiquery','queries'=>$fql)));
var_dump(time()-$stime);
```

The result is that the process takes me **5 seconds!!**
I wish to cut that time off, and make it much faster.

How do offer to improve that process?:

1. Getting the friends information using the client side?
2. Cache the friend list(uids) of each user in my database?(is it possible to add subscribing to the friend-list?)
3. Chacing the result?(this is not good option, because I want the most updated results)?
4. Split it to query per event. **I already tried it, and its takes much longer**

Comment: How many events are we talking about? And you don’t need multi-queries here, you can put the first query into the second as a subquery: `… AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

Comment: about 5-15 events per query. and I belive its option that I'll handle multiple requests to the api at the same time..

Comment: I succeed to decrease the process time by handling the intersection manully in php(getting all the attendees, getting all the friends, and manipulate the arrays).
But it still takes me long time(3s) for event with few attendees.